# Real URLS with Single Page Applications?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I was using react router for one of my projects, so react is frontend library and routes are managed by react router and backend views are in django and apis in django rest

So i was going through the react-router documentation and I came across this:-

> Configuring Your Server
>   Your server must be ready to handle real URLs. When the app first loads at / it will probably work, but as the user navigates around and then hits refresh at /accounts/23 your web server will get a request to /accounts/23. You will need it to handle that URL and include your JavaScript application in the response.**

I was wondering how would this work with django views.

Comment: Hello, this is a rather subjective answer (that's why I add a comment instead of an answer) however I believe that you shouldn't follow this path unless you are willing to bite the bullet and create a full single-page-application. Since you have backend views in django as you mention then I recommend just using hashed routing for your client-side routing. I have written a rather extensive opinion on that on my post about redux: http://spapas.github.io/2016/03/02/react-redux-tutorial/#store-js (check my comment on HashHistory vs BrowserHistory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the development server, you simply set up a route for everything that doesn't start with `api/` or `static/` to return your basic `app.html` file. Example

```
class AppHTMLView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        fn = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "app", "app.html")
        with open(fn, 'r') as fh:
            return HttpResponse(fh.read())
```

And on your production server, you configure Nginx accordingly. Something like this

```
...
location / {
    root /var/www/example.com/static_files/;
    try_files '' /app.html =404;
}
```

But that's not in any way specific to React, but common to all single page apps.

Comment: yeah it should be common for all single page apps i will edit the question title, nginx one is the best solution i feel